# rails difference between two dates inside .where

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my logic
I want to get the closest 4 more expensive mobiles to a specific mobile `@mobile` but under one condition the difference between the release dates of the two mobiles is not more than a year and half
Here is the query

```
high = Mobile.where("price >= #{@mobile.price} AND id != #{@mobile.id} AND visible = true").where("ABS(release_date - #{@mobile.release_date}) > ?", 18.months).order(price: :ASC).first(4)
```

The first .where() works perfectly but the second is not working and I get this error

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 UTC) > 46656000) ORDER BY `mobiles`.`price` ASC LIMIT 4' at line 1: SELECT `mobiles`.* FROM `mobiles` WHERE (price >= 123123.0 AND id != 11 AND visible = true) AND (ABS(release_date - 2016-04-10 00:00:00 UTC) > 46656000) ORDER BY `mobiles`.`price` ASC LIMIT 4
```

I think now you can get my logic. What is the right syntax to achieve it?

Comment: check types first - then, better use scopes (and chain them if needed) thus it will be easier to inspect. currently it is  pain to follow what is going on there. 

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of tips here:

- It is a dangerous practice to concatenate variables into your queries using the `"#{}"` operator.  Doing so bypasses query parameterization and could leave your app open to [SQL injection](https://rails-sqli.org/).  Instead, use `"?"` in your where clause.
- The reason MySQL is giving you an error is because you are concatenating a string into your query without encapsulating it in quotes.

With these two things in mind, I would start by refactoring your query like so:

```
high = Mobile.where("price >= ?", @mobile.price)
         .where.not(id: @mobile.id)
         .where(visible: true)
         .where("ABS(release_date - ?) > 46656000", @mobile.release_date)
         .order(price: :ASC).first(4)
```

You will note that I replaced `18.months` with `46656000`.  This saves a few clock cycles in the Rails app.  Depending on your database schema, the last where clause may not work.  The modification below may end up working better.

As a further refinement, you could refactor your last where clause to look for a release date that is between 18 months before `@mobile.release_date` and 18 months after.  The saves your MySql database from having to do the math on each record and may lead to better performance:

```
.where(release_date: (@mobile.release_date - 18.months)..(@mobile.release_date + 18.months) )
```

I do not know your database schema, so you may run into date conversion problems with the code above.  I recommend you play with it in the Rails console.

Comment: This really solves the syntax error and yes I have some conversion issues and I am working on it right now. Thank you very much

Comment: I  am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Range to query between dates/times:

```
Mobile.where("price >= ?", @mobile.price)
      .where.not(id: @mobile.id)
      .where(release_date: 18.months.ago..Time.now)
      .order(price: :ASC)
      .first(4)
```

Comment: actually I want the time difference between the two mobiles to be 18 months not 18 months from now.